# Having trouble downloading mysql

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-10.04, package-management

So I am downloading mysql for DVWA (https://medium.com/@sinxloud/setup-install-dvwa-into-your-linux-distribution-d76dc3b80357) and I get:

```
root@kali:~# *sudo apt install mysql-server*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
root@kali:~# *mysql -u root -p*
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
root@kali:~#
```

Anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `apt update` and `apt upgrade`, then try to download MySQL-server again. Maybe the package lists weren't updated on your computer.

By the way, why are you using Ubuntu 10? It reached end of life many years ago which means it won't receive security updates anymore, which makes it vulnerable. You should upgrade to a newer release.